# Reuse flow class declaration for class definition

Tags: javascript, class, flowtype

How can I reuse my class declaration in this case without copy-pasting all members ofthe class definition?

```
declare type A {
 a: string;
}

class A extends EventEmitter {

 foo() {
  this.a // error property not found
 }
}
```

I thought flow would recognize that `class` A is an instance of `type` A but it doesn't.

Comment: The `A` that you declared with `declare type` is not the same `A` that you defined with `class A`. It sounds like you what you are looking for is a base class, but you can't do that because you don't want to always have to extend `EventEmitter`?

Comment: How can I declare a Type for my Class A ?

Comment: A type is automatically created for your class A. You can't declare it.

Answer (score 4):

I think you have misunderstood what `type` means in Flow.

First of all, in your code there are two things called `A`, which are overlapping. Let's rename them, so we can talk about them properly:

```
type T {
  a: string;
}
```

Here, `T` is any Javascript object that has a property called `a` that is a string.

```
class C extends EventEmitter {
  foo() {
    this.a // error property not found
  }
}
```

`C` is the name of your class but *also* Flow has made a type of the same name, which is the type of all objects that are instances of `C` or a subclass of `C`. `C` doesn't have an `a` attribute, so the error is expected. You can't make it into a `T` because it *isn't* at `T`. The only way to make it a `T` is to give it an `a: number` attribute:

```
class C extends EventEmitter {
  a: number;
  foo() {
    this.a
  }
}
```

And now any instance of `C` is also a `T` because it conforms to `T`'s interface:

```
const t: T = new C(); // this is now ok
```

---

Your original question is about avoiding duplication of attributes. Flow doesn't provide additional shortcuts for defining `classes`, but it does provide shortcuts for defining types, via [mixins](https://flowtype.org/docs/declarations.html#mixins). However, I don't think it will do exactly what you want. You'll be able to do something like:

```
declare class SharedProps {
    a: number;
}
declare class A mixins SharedProps {
    b: string;
}
```

However, this will only declare *types*, not implementations. You will still need to implement the classes somewhere, and this might not save you much effort.

Comment: Thank you @peterhall I already understand this concept. I think this shows that class support is very rare. My current situation force me to manage an extra type for every class. I hope someone else will see this as a show stopper too.

Comment: I created an issue on the flow repository https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/3211